# Checking conditions for graduated optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, expectation, non-convex-optimization

I am currently reading Hazan et. al.'s recent paper[[1](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v48/hazanb16.pdf)] on graduated nonconvex optimization. Letting $f$ be an arbitrary, possibly nonconvex function, its smoothed version on scale $\delta$ is defined as:

$$
\hat{f}_{\delta}(\mathbf{x}) \triangleq \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{u} \sim \mathbb{B}} \left[ f(\mathbf{x} + \delta \mathbf{u}) \right] \qquad (1)
$$

where $\mathbb{B}$ is the unit ball.

In Section 3.2, the notion of an *$(a, \sigma)$-nice* function is introduced, which depends on two conditions:

1. **Centering property**: $\forall \delta > 0$, letting $\mathbf{x}_{\delta}^* = \mbox{argmin} \hat{f}_{a \delta} (\mathbf{x})$, there exists $\mathbf{x}_{\delta / 2}^* = \mbox{argmin} \hat{f}_{a \delta / 2}(\mathbf{x})$ such that $\|\mathbf{x}^*_{\delta} - \mathbf{x}_{\delta / 2}^*\| < \delta / 2$.
2. **Local strong convexity**: $\forall \delta > 0$, $\mathbf{x}_{\delta}^* = \mbox{argmin} \hat{f}_{a \delta} (\mathbf{x})$, then the function $\hat{f}_{a \delta}(\mathbf{x})$ is $\sigma$-strongly convex over $\mathbb{B}_{3 \delta}(\mathbf{x}^*)$ (the euclidean ball with radius $3 \delta$ centered around $\mathbf{x}_{\delta}^*$).

I understand that the first property essentially means that if we transition from a scale $\delta$ to a more "fine" scale $\delta /2 $, the new minima will not shift too much a position with respect to the scale change, while the second property ensures that after shifting scale the optimization procedure remains within a convex neighbourhood.

My question pertains to how one could verify (or disprove) the validity of the above conditions for some arbitrary function $f$. The authors seem to take them for granted for the parameters of a single-layer neural network trained on a square loss, but in the relevant section (Sec. 7) they fail to mention the parameters $\sigma, a$ that they used for training.

I'm also confused by the fact that $\hat{f}$ is defined as the expectation of $f$ over a scaled euclidean ball, which makes it harder for me to imagine a way to check local properties such as convexity for arbitrary $f$. More specifically, I am dealing with a loss function

$$
J(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \|\max_j(x_j + k_{ij}) - d_i\|_p
$$

where $(\mathbf{k}_i, d_i)$ are data pairs, and $||\cdot||_p$ is some suitable $\ell_p$ norm. Is it possible to write $\hat{J}_{\delta}(\mathbf{x})$ in closed (or easily computable) form?  More generally, how would one go about proving or disproving conditions (1, 2) for a function defined as the expectation of values over a set?

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: This is about a mathematical paper, so you should probably ask it on MathOverflow (or maybe cstheory.stackexchange since it's about neural nets).